# Where can I find a list of meta posts on what types of questions are not a good fit for this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

In order to give new and novice users a more readily available for what questions we don't like to see, I'd like to propose compiling a list of what types of questions are not a good fit for our site, each with a brief sentence or two summarizing, why they are not a good fit or guidelines to follow to ensure a good response.

Feel free to list examples, opinions, and specific-topics as well.

I'll compile a final list in this meta post.